# what is alternative function for canvas.drawColor in codenameone

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I want to use android canvas.drawColor() function in codenameone. what is alternative function for this usage in codenameone or how can i implement a function like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [Javadoc](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/index.html), `Graphics` class has 2 methods that will do the job.

First call `setColor(int RGB)` and then `fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight())`.

This is equivalent to `canvas.drawColor()`, which in fact is just a shortcut for filling canvas with specified color.

Comment: Correct, there is also the new Shape API which includes a fill option. Its faster on the devices where its supported since it uses GPU acceleration.